# Security in Flutter apps

Tags: flutter, security, jailbreak, tampering

I noticed that for flutter there isn't a plugin or similar that  manages security vulnerabilities of apps.

The code can be **obfuscated** with the --obfuscate option in build phase.

For the **other aspects** there are some libraries like:
[flutter_security](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_security) and [flutter_jailbreak_detection](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_jailbreak_detection)
that are not very well documented or are limited to only some aspect of the security field.

There is then [freeRASP](https://pub.dev/packages/freerasp) that seems to be more complete but the free version could not be a good idea for a product project.

How do you secure your application to check jailbreak/roos, anti-tampering and so on?

**NB**: I know that is impossible to protect an app against the 100% of the attacks and so on, but I need to add some controls in order to pass vulnerability team tests :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had a similar problem. I've ended up using semgrep as SAST and freeRASP for the rest of it.

Comment: So there aren't a lot of alternatives....
could you please explain me how to generate the hash code for the signing certificate to use with freerasp?

Comment: Yes, true... nothing out there :D For certs, I used cert by fastlane that does most of the heavy lifting there. For semgrep, I am writing custom rules myself since there is almost nothing out there for Flutter, but OWASP Top 10 could be pretty language agnostic, so I just create a custom ruleset there.